# Bash script to backup from S3 to GC

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I'm working on a script to backup S3 to GC everyday. I'm not sure if my script has any potential bug or error that might have destroyed anything from both sides? The data is quite sensitive and I don't want to mess it up. Anything is welcomed.

```
#!/bin/sh

if hash aws 2>/dev/null; then
    echo 'awscli is installed.'
else
    echo 'Please install awscli by running sudo pip install awscli'
    exit
fi

if hash gsutil 2>/dev/null; then
    echo 'gsutil is installed.'
else
    echo 'Please install gsutil by running sudo pip install gsutil'
fi

if env | grep -q ^BACKUP_TO_EMAIL=
then
    echo "After backup is done email will be send to $BACKUP_TO_EMAIL"
else
    echo "BACKUP_TO_EMAIL is not set please set it"
    exit
fi

if env | grep -q ^S3_BUCKET=
then
    echo "Checking if $S3_BUCKET exists"
    if aws s3 ls "s3://$S3_BUCKET" 2>&1 | grep -q 'AllAccessDisabled'   
    then
        echo "bucket $S3_BUCKET doesn't exist please check again."
        exit
    fi
else
    echo 'S3_BUCKET is not set please set it'
    exit
fi

if env | grep -q ^GC_BUCKET=
then
    echo "Checking if $GC_BUCKET exists"
    if gsutil ls "gs://$GC_BUCKET" 2>&1 | grep -q 'AccessDeniedException'
    then
        echo "bucket $GC_BUCKET doesn't exist please check again."
        exit
    fi
else
    echo 'GC_BUCKET is not set please set it'
    exit
fi

echo "Backing up now..."
#`gsutil -m rsync -r s3://$S3_BUCKET gs://$GC_BUCKET`

echo "Creating new backup folder"
datestamp=$(date +%m%d%y)
mkdir $datestamp

echo "Downloading backup"
aws s3 sync "s3://$S3_BUCKET" $datestamp

echo "Compressing site backup"
tar -zcvf $datestamp.tar.gz $datestamp
file=$datestamp.tar.gz
rm -rf $datestamp

echo "Uploading to GC"
gsutil cp $file "gs://$GC_BUCKET"

echo "Deleting temporary files"
rm $file

echo "Sending email"
body="Backup is complete and the file is in gs://$GC_BUCKET/$file"

echo $body | mail $BACKUP_TO_EMAIL -s "S3 to GS backup"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks mostly pretty good.

---

When exiting with error, it's a good practice to specify a non-zero exit code, for example `exit 1`.

---

This looks odd:

> ```
> if env | grep -q ^S3_BUCKET=
> then
>     echo "Checking if $S3_BUCKET exists"
>     if aws s3 ls "s3://$S3_BUCKET" 2>&1 | grep -q 'AllAccessDisabled'
> ```

It's odd to check environment variables using `env | grep`.
And in this example, it looks error-prone too,
because `S3_BUCKET` might be defined empty, with no values.

I don't know `aws`, but I have a strong feeling that in case of `S3_BUCKET=` (empty) you would rather raise an error than run execute `aws s3 ls "s3://"`.

I suggest to replace with a simple variable check:

```
if test "$S3_BUCKET"; then
```

---

In this code:

> ```
> tar -zcvf $datestamp.tar.gz $datestamp
> file=$datestamp.tar.gz
> ```

It would be better to set `file` first, and then use it in the `tar`

---

I like to avoid nested `if` statements when possible. For example here:

> ```
> if env | grep -q ^S3_BUCKET=
> then
>     echo "Checking if $S3_BUCKET exists"
>     if aws s3 ls "s3://$S3_BUCKET" 2>&1 | grep -q 'AllAccessDisabled'   
>     then
>         echo "bucket $S3_BUCKET doesn't exist please check again."
>         exit
>     fi
> else
>     echo 'S3_BUCKET is not set please set it'
>     exit
> fi
> ```

I would flatten by inverting the outer `if`:

```
if test ! "$S3_BUCKET"
then
    echo 'S3_BUCKET is not set please set it'
    exit 1
fi

echo "Checking if $S3_BUCKET exists"
if aws s3 ls "s3://$S3_BUCKET" 2>&1 | grep -q 'AllAccessDisabled'   
then
    echo "bucket $S3_BUCKET doesn't exist please check again."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what `test ! "$S3_BUCKET"` do?

Comment: It will be true if the variable is undefined, or defined but empty. In bash an empty string is "false"